# How to retrieve the arguments from command prompt using Getopt::Long?

Tags: perl, command-line-arguments

The requirement is

```
perl prg.pl --product --param Product1 --from FilePath
```

where `--product` specifies the reference to the function that has to accept the parameter `Product1`, and the `FilePath` is the path of the file to be searched for the product.

```
GetOptions('product=s'=>\&getproduct, 'param=s'=>\$param,'from=s'=>\$from);
```

In spite of this, while running the Perl program, it gives an error that the values product and from are uninitialized.
Can you help me solve this issue?

Comment: `getproduct` is to be passed as an reference. So it should be `'product=s' => \&getproduct` and also `param` and `from`.

Comment: @vkk05, The `\ ` was there, but hidden by bad formatting.

Comment: In the future, please provide the error messages, and please provide a minimal, runnable demonstration of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You indicate that the `product` option requires a value (`=s`), so

```
             Value for --product. (Not an option.)
             |
             |       Doesn't start with `-`, so option parsing ends.
             |       |
          vvvvvvv vvvvvvvv
--product --param Product1 --from FilePath
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                             |
                             Not options, so found in @ARGV.
```

Fix:

```perl
GetOptions(
   'help|h|?' => \&help,
   'product'  => \$product,
   'param=s'  => \$param,
   'from=s'   => \$from,
)
   or usage();

@ARGV == 0
   or usage("Too many arguments.");
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60121085/589924) for a sample implementation of `usage` and `help`.